# Google Drive is showing my application as virus?

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api, nsis

I developed my application with Qt 5.2.1 and MinGW compiler.The installer is created with NSIS and doesnt even require admin privilege.
I use [blogger](http://smovault.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_2.html) as my application's website, and post Google Drive links to download the setup files.
Suddenly Drive is now showing my application as a virus, even though I checked with virustital.com and the Windows anti-virus software.
I have not received any response to the post I submitted on their forum.
So I would like to know if there is any known common cause for this problem and whether that can be resolved.

PS: I have previously used the same Google services for another software that I developed few years ago, but never ran into such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably false-positive alarm.

Sometimes NSIS generated installer is recognized as virus (which is wrong).
Write to the AV company (I am not sure which AV software G drive uses) and report this problem - they should whitelist your software.

Sometimes simply rebuilding the installer helps too :)

Or my last idea is to remove 'dangerous' code from installer: many times inetC and various other internet calls are suspicious.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! Can you please tell me whom should I recommend to whitelist my installer? I already posted in the Drive help forum, but haven't received a reply yet. I do not understand why it should consider my setup as virus, I am not even seeking admin privilege, nor doing any networking in the installation. Just opening my blog page after installation succeeds.